# Google Apps Script -> write Text from Document to Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I got one Google Document and fead it via GAS with multipe Data from another Google Sheet (numbers as well as long text).
After this insertion I modify some of the imported Texts, stored in different Paragraphs -> DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody.appendParagraph('...'). When i am done with this modification, I would like to safe the modified texts back to my sheet, but i have no glue how to do so.

Could anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot and have a nice Day.

Comment: If you are already capable of reading from a document and writing to a spreadsheet, why can't you read from the sheet and write back to the document ?! What exact dilemma are you facing ?

Comment: No no, its exactly the other way. I am able to read from a sheet and write to a document, but not able to do it backwards. Thats the problem. :)

Comment: DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() ?

Comment: Yes, but this is only the document itself. How can i access one specific paragraph within the document? I would like to write those Text back to a sheet and have no idea how to do so.

Comment: `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs()` ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your Answer was right that was i was looking for! Thank you very much! With your hint i could write all the Paragraphs in an array and work with them. Thanks a lot and have a nice Day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs()`, you can access a document's paragraphs. Of course you can replace `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` with a reference to a document you are handling.